# Lightbox image max-height = user screen height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm building an image gallery for a photographer. You can find the site [here.](http://jefferson.microdesign.nl/rauwkost/rauwkost%20gallery/index.html)
What I'm trying to do is set the height of the image so that it will never fall off the screen. In other words:

```
lightbox img { max-height:100%; max-width:auto; }
```

This however, doesn't work. Since my `ul` parent's height is larger than the screen.

The images are all around 1000px or higher. And ofcourse we don't want to offer them falling off the screen. Does anyone have any idea how I might solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

With pure CSS you could use media queries for example: (attention -> CSS3!)

```
@media screen and (max-height:700px) {
    #lightbox img { max-height: 690px; }
}
```

With jquery its more dynamic and even simpler:

```
$('#lightbox img').css('max-height', $(document).height()));
```